# Why does Google Calendar move events in a different (non-DST) timezone 1 hour backward?

Tags: google-calendar, time-zone

I'm currently residing UTC+3: UTC+2 standard time zone, +1 for daylight saving time (DST).

For a trip I'm planning, I'm trying to set a new event in Google Calendar, which takes place in a different timezone, and that different timezone does not have any DST adjustment. However, immediately after I set it it shows the event as being 1 hour earlier.

So I set the event to 13:08 in that other timezone, save, and when I enter the event again it shows it in 12:08, for that same timezone.

If it's an error, how do I solve this? If it isn't, why does it happen and how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Events can only display on your calendar in one time zone at a time.  I'm not certain, but it sounds like you created the event for 13:08 in UTC+4, which Google Calendar was (correctly) showing to you as 12:08 in UTC+3 (your main time zone).

If you want to see events in another time zone (such as once you arrive in the other country), you would need to go to your Calendar Settings (in the gear menu) and change "Your current time zone".  Or, instead of changing your current timezone, in the same place in settings you can add additional time zones.

Comment: No, the event was created for a time in UTC-8, and in any case the calendar made it clear the event is marked in that timezone, not mine.

Comment: Hmmm... Help me diagnose this: What are the specific _names_ of your home zone and the zone to which you were travelling?  And what was the actual date of the event?  Except for a few Pacific Islands, most populated areas in UTC–8 _do_ observe DST, but possibly on different dates than expected.

Comment: You actually raise an interesting point. I scheduled a flight from PST (which observes DST) to Hawaii (which doesn't) - that might have caused the bug...

Comment: Yeah, if it was between mid-March and early-November, US Pacific Time would have been on UTC–7, while Hawai'i is on UTC–10 year-round.