# Is there a way to show Google Calendar events in local time?

Tags: google-calendar, calendar, time-zone

AFAICT, in Google Calendar, a calendar has a time zone and an event has a time zone.  So you can enter an event and specify that it takes place at, say, 12:00 Eastern Time.  If your calendar is also set to Eastern Time, the event will display at 12:00, but if the calendar is in Pacific Time, it will display at 9:00.  So far so good.

But, now I'm planning a tour that will go across time zones, and I want to be able to display events in local time, for example: I and my calendar are in Eastern time.  I plan an event in Los Angeles that will take place at 12:00 **in Los Angeles**.  I create the event for 12:00 and specify Pacific time for the event.

The problem is: when I view this event in my calendar, it's at 3:00.  This is correct in the sense of indicating when the event will be happening relative to New York time, but I would much rather see it relative to the local time in LA.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to change your calendar's time zone while you are in the other time zone.  I don't really like that option, but I discovered that you can add additional time zones to your calendar's display.  Go to the calendar settings, and right below the time zone you can select an additional time zone to display.

(https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/24171/21239)

Answer (score 2):

My workaround is to include the local time in the event's title.  At least you can see it when you look at the calendar even though the calendar's scale may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in planing a tour in a different time zone with Google Calendar. My work around is to show my Google tour calendar on my iPhone with the "Time Zone Override" feature in the iPhone's calendar setting. After you set LA to be overrided, you will see your tour schedule with the "right time", so that a Google Calendar even at 12:00 in LA time zone will show up as 12:00 on my iPhone when I am in Toronto time zone.

Answer (score 0):

For me this makes google calender useless for trips, as it puts flights, etc on the WRONG DATE! For example I have a flight in the calender at 3am but it's really 6pm the previous day. My solution is to remove all internaltional events from the calender and write my own spreadsheet or other system...

Comment: I more or less solved my problem by using Google Calendar as the storage for the events, and when I'm actually traveling and updating my computer time zone, it shows the events properly. But I wrote a little script to extract these events and write them to an HTML page for viewing, and I manually convert the time to local for this purpose.